# Search a string and delete the whole line containg the string in php

Tags: php, config, haproxy

I need to search a string in .cfg file, and delete the whole line. I'm  using  `file_get_contents` to retrieve the the data in .cfg file, and I'm storing it in a variable, searching is good but not knowing how to delete the whole line?

I have a string in following way:

user `$username` insecure-password `$password`

I want to search `$username` and delete the whole line.

Comment: *... searching is good ...*. So the question is how to delete a line? You could add the valid lines to a new array and save that.

Comment: can you use fgets instead of file_get_contents for this purpose? if so you can skip that line if it matches your search.

Comment: explain me how to do it? i m new to programming

Comment: i used fgets, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use a little Regex to match the line:

```
<?php

$file = 'blah
etc
user delboy1978uk insecure-password 123456
etc
etc';

$regex = '#\nuser\s\w+\sinsecure-password\s.+\n#';
preg_match($regex, $file, $matches);
$file = str_replace($matches[0], "\n", $file);

echo $file;
```

Which outputs:

```
blah 
etc 
etc 
etc
```

See it here: https://3v4l.org/BcDWK

Comment: i have a file full of : user `$username` insecure- password `$password` with unique usernames

Comment: i'll do that, could you please explain meaning of regex  : : '#\nuser\s\w+\sinsecure-password\s.+\n#'

Comment: one more doubt. suppose if i want to search a username and replace with username and new password, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

With this method you can read each config file line by line search in each line.

```
$h = fopen('yourfile', 'r') ;
$match = 'username' ;

$output = [] ;

if ($h) {
    while (!feof($h)) {
        $line = fgets($h);

        //your current search function, which search each line
        if ( your_search_function($line, $match) === false) {
            //array $output will not contain matching lines.
            $output[] = $line;
        }
    }
    fclose($h);

    //write back to file or do something else with $output
    $hw = fopen('yourfile', 'w') ;
    if( $hw ) {
        foreach( $output as $line ) {
            fputs($hw, $line) ;
        }
        fclose($hw) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @tan, i ll try this. one more doubt. suppose if i want to search a username  and replace with username and new password, how can i do that?

Comment: you can. add the following line as else part of your if condition. $output[] = "user $username ... ";